# XMLHttpRequest to get a sound from a different domain

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, web-audio-api, arraybuffer

I am currently playing with the Web Audio API and I am looking at buffering and play a source of sound coming from a different domain.

I did quite a bit or researches including on stackoverflow and it seems there are solutions to do cross domain requests (JSONP, YQL...) to query html, json, xml... but nothing to capture an audio source. The standard method in order to pick up a sound source is by using an XMLHttpRequest and forcing the response to be of a type of arrayBuffer:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request.open("GET", url);
```

the request.response can afterwards be a buffer that can be played.

This seems to work with a "url" that points to an audio file of the same domain. Is there a way to get the response of a XMLHttpRequest requesting an audio source from an external domain?

I tried the **http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?** with a select query but there is no way to pick up an audio source from the tables (according to https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/).

Any idea is welcome.

Many thanks!!

Comment: There are only two ways: 1) the server hosting the audio (on a different domain) sends the appropriate Access-Control headers in its response (which it sounds like it isn't) and 2) setup a server that you control (on the same domain) to proxy the request.

Answer (score 2):

This would only work if the audio file you're requesting is on a server that supports CORS (and you use CORS in the request) - you can't just arbitrarily grab sound files off other servers (as that would enable cross-origin data access).  http://enable-cors.org/.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer cwilso. I tried already CORS and the server I request the audio files from don't support it.

Comment: You could use a CORS proxy. It's not the best solution for production code, but if you just want to test something out, it works. For eg. http://www.corsproxy.com/

Comment: The link above `corsproxy.com` redirects to a phishing site.